# WinAPI CreateProcess and quoting of arguments

Tags: c++, c, winapi

`CreateProcess` has 3 string arguments: `lpApplicationName`, `lpCommandLine`, `lpCurrentDirectory`.

I tried to quote that args and found that sometimes quotes break my code.
Can someone explain rules of quoting?

Works fine:

```
NULL
"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe\" myparam1 myparam2"
"C:\\some path"
```

Does not work:

```
NULL
"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe\" myparam1 myparam2"
"\"C:\\some path\""
```

Works fine:

```
"C:\\some path\\my app.exe"
"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe\" myparam1 myparam2"
"C:\\some path"
```

Does not work:

```
"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe\""
"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe\" myparam1 myparam2"
"C:\\some path"
```

P.S. Sorry, formatting of StackOverflow didn't show my backslashes in the examples above and I missed it... Now fixed

Comment: Remember that *all* backslashes in a C string have to be escaped; all your C strings need to use two backslashes as a path separator. The rules for quoting arguments are described in the documentation for the `CommandLineToArgvW()` function and on various places on the The Old New Thing blog.

Comment: The application path and current directory should not be quoted. Quoting is for command lines, not for paths and directories.

Comment: @RaymondChen But if you look at docs for CreateProcess you will see that lpApplicationName must be quoted. Broken docs?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the docs for CreateProcess where it says that lpApplicationName must be quoted. It says that if lpApplicationName is NULL, then the first token from the lpCommandLine is used, and that you need to quote the lpCommandLine.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry. You are right. I misread docs. Seems that "The application path and current directory should not be quoted" is the answer for my question ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes belong *only* in the `lpCommandLine` argument.  Both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCurrentDirectory` specify filenames, and therefore must not contain embedded quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as already highlighted by andlabs, in C any backslash have to be escaped with a backslash.
Said that the rules used by MS for interpretation of command line arguments are somewhat complex and tricky.
They are explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx.
I don't even try to add an extra word ...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But quoting of command line works fine. What does not work - quoting of lpApplicationName and lpCurrentDirectory

Comment: In that case the general rules for C string escaping are valid.

Comment: Because of escaping of other params

Comment: Still not clear. The strings you wrote are the strings you coded in C or their translation? Something like `"\"C:\\some path\\my app.exe" myparam1 myparam2"` should trigger a compiler error.